# Provide endDate to previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to provide an EndDate when the MainAccountNum already exist. The endDate should be applied to the MainAccountNumb with the earliest startDate.

So If I have a create table statement like this:

```
   Create Table ods.CustomerId(
    ScreenDate INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerNum nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    MainAccountNum nvarchar(40) not null,
    ServiceNum nvarchar(40) not null,
    StartDate datetime not null,
    EndDate datetime not null,
    UpdatedBy nvarchar(50) not null);
```

and say I encounter something in the CustomerNum, MainAccountNum, StartDate, and EndDate like below:

```
1467823,47382906,2019-08-26 00:00:00.000, Null
1467833,47382906,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000, null
```

When the second record is inserted with that same MainAccountNum the first record should get the startDate of the New Record. The startDate has a default constraint as GetDat() so in the end it should look like:

```
1467823,47382906,2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000
1467833,47382906,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000, null
```

Please Provide code examples of how this can be accomplished

Comment: What have you so far? Have you looked at `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Comment: @Larnu No I have not what would that code look like?

Comment: Is your data schema set in stone? If not, I would recommend removing the dates from the customer table and instead have an Account_Service table that records the dates and the action (start, end, modified, etc.). You can easily get the start/end data from that, and you won't end up with duplicate account records.

Comment: [LEAD (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Do you want to "apply" this end date to A) the data that is shown by a query, or B) to modify the actual table when a new row is created?

Comment: @TheImpaler modify the table when a new row is created. So when the record is being insert with the same MainAccountNum as one currently in the table it will take the old one and give it an end date

Answer (score 0):

In the stored procedure used to insert new record, have something like

```
begin tran
declare @startDate datetime

select top 1 @oldStartDate = StartDate 
from ods.CustomerId 
where MainAccountNum = @mainAccountNum 
order by StartDate asc

if @@rowcount > 0
    update ods.CustomerId set EndDate = @startDate 
    where MainAccountNum = @mainAccountNum and StartDate = @oldStartDate

insert ... <your new record here>
commit
```

I am assuming that (MainAccountNum, StartDate) tuple is unique and can be used as a key. If not, you have to use whatever is unique for your update statement.